# ! Missing number, treated as zero. \let \centering

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subfloats

```
\section{Azimuthal Angle}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b][0.3\textwidth]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{D:/Project/Documentation/Images/muon_phi}
\caption{The azimuthal angle of muons}
\label{muon_phi}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How is `subfigure` defined? Are you using a package like the older `subfigure` or the newer `subfig`? Then see my answer.

Comment: If you're using the `subcaption` package, please say so.

Answer (score 2):

the subfigure width argument needs curly braces ie

```
\begin{subfigure}{3.0\textwidth}
```

however i think that seeing as you have only one image the subfigure environment is somewhat redundant. You can just as easily control position, size, caption numbering etc. using just figure and \includegraphics. (the above solution uses subcaption package)